# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0+}\left[\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{x^{1/2}\sin(x)}\right]=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

This exercise $$\lim_{x\to 0+}\left[\frac{1}{x^\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)}\right]$$ was in my calculus III test at college, after trying hard to solve it I was not really able to do so, I know intuitively that this limit equals 0 but did not find an appropriate way to prove it, as the limit gives an indeterminate form $\infty - \infty$. I worked out the fractions and got $$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{x^\frac{1}{2}\sin(x) - x^\frac{3}{2} }{x^2\sin(x)}$$ which gives me an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$, then using L'hopitals rule, the limit starts getting uglier as more indeterminate forms keep showing up. My college test is over, but, still I want to find out how to solve this limit, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you correctly recall it? The reason I ask is that it seems to me that the second term is essentially $1/x^{3/2}$, which blows up faster than the first term, so they can't cancel...

Comment: I'm sorry I had written one of the fractions incorrectly, question edited, now that is the real exercise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't rationalise the denominator. Instead, stick with
$$\frac{\sin x - x}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}\sin x}.$$
Applying L'Hopital's rule,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos x - 1}{\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}\sin x + x^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos x} &= \frac{(\cos x - 1)(\cos x + 1)}{\left(\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}\sin x + x^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos x\right)(\cos x + 1)} \\
&= \frac{-\sin^2 x}{\left(\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}\sin x + x^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos x\right)(\cos x + 1)} \\
&= \frac{-x^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\frac{\sin x}{x} + \cos x\right)(\cos x + 1)} \\
&\to \frac{-0 \cdot 1}{\left(\frac{3}{2} \cdot 1 + 1\right)(1 + 1)} = 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: oh boy, this is what I was looking for, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. By the Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 0$, one gets
$$
\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}6+O(x^5)
$$ giving
$$
\frac1{\sin x}=\frac1x+\frac{x}6+O(x^3)
$$ and, as $x \to 0^+$,
$$
\frac1{x^{1/2}\sin x}=\frac1{x^{3/2}}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}6+O(x^{5/2})
$$
Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Hi, we had not been given Taylor series at college yet, so I guess there has to be another(simpler) way to solve it, anyways, thanks for your time and effort ;)